# Integrate Skype with my application using python

Tags: python

I did lots of R & D and couldn't find API for Python which can help me to integrate my application with Skype .
Is there any way by which i can import all my skype chat on my application & i can send receive message to people via my own application instead using skype client.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Give a try to this one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Skype4Py/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

Look at: https://developer.skype.com/

And: http://sourceforge.net/projects/skype4py/

This two are enough to serve your purpose.